# Why are these languages not regular?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Show that the following languages are not regular:

$(1)\ L=\left\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n>k \land n,m,k>0\right\}$

$(2)\ L=\left\{a^nb^mc^k\mid m>k \land n,m,k>0\right\}$

I've difficulties showing that these two languages are not regular by using the Pumping Lemma. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using the closure of regular languages under reversal and under intersection. Alternatively, you can use Nerode's criterion.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for the first language I wanted to try with the first method but honestly I don't know how to proceed exactly.

Comment: @Raphael I don't find your [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) post helpful. It is nothing than a couple of special examples  together with the lemma statement. You cannot reduce all examples to your post. Every problem requires individual approach. So, I strongly recommend you not to mark every post that asks to help prove that a language is not regular.

Comment: @fade2black The question as posted is not suited for this site; see e.g. [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/775/98). Closing as duplicate of the reference question is the most helpful thing to do at this point, and it *certainly* answers the question "any suggestions?". If you disagree with this long-standing policy, feel free to open a post no [meta].

Comment: Regarding your critique, all reference questions reps. their answers strive to exhibit generally applicable techniques. Of course, every proof is different; however, there are similarities and patterns. "Every problem requires individual approach." -- this is definitely a wrong statement, at least the way I understand it. If it were true, experience would not help you answering such problem statements, but it clearly does.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier to prove if you first note note $$ L' = \{a^nb^mc^k|n\leq k \land n,m,k>0\} = \{a^nb^mc^k | n,m,k \geq 1 \} - \{a^nb^mc^k|n>k \land n,m,k>0\}$$ So if $\{a^nb^mc^k|n>k \land n,m,k>0 \}$ is regular then so is $\{a^nb^mc^k|n\leq k \land n,m,k>0\}$ since $\{a^nb^mc^k | n,m,k \geq 1 \}$ is regular and the difference of regular sets is a regular set.

But $L'$ is not regular, a contradiction. If you are NOT convinced that $L'$ is not regular then see the following proof using the Pumping lemma.

---

So, let's prove that $L' = \{a^nb^mc^k|n\leq k \land n,m,k>0\}$ is not regular using the Pumping lemma in order to obtain contradiction.

**The Pumping Lemma:**

Let $L$ be a regular set. Then **there is a constant** $n$ such that if $z$ **is any word in** $L$, and $|z| \geq n$ we may write $z = uvw$ in such a way that $|uv| \leq n$, $|v| \geq 1$, and **for all** $i \geq 0$, $uv^iw \in L$.

**How to prove**

1) Select the language you wish to to prove irregular.

2) The "adversary" picks $n$, the constant mentioned in the Pumping lemma. Once it has been picked, it may not be changed (fix it).

3) Select a string $z$  in $L$. Your choice may depend implicitly on the value of $n$.

We choose $z = a^nb^nc^{n+1}$ (since $n < n+1$, $z \in L$).

4) The "adversary" breaks $z$ into $u$, $v$, and $w$, subject to the constraints that $|uv| \leq n$ and $|v|$.

5) You achieve a contradiction to the pumping lemma by showing that **there exists** $i$ such that $uv^iw \notin L$.

Since $z = a^nb^nc^{n+1} = uvw$ and $|uv| \leq n$, $uv$ is a string consisting of only $a$s, and so is $v$. If we choose $i=n+2$ then we get 
$uvvw$ such that $uv^{n+2}w$ has at least $n+2$ $a$s which is greater than $n+1$ $c$s which does not belong to $L'$. But this contradicts to the Pumping lemma.

You may try to prove the second language  yourself.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).